# Video Transition? 3 Parts of a Pic?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, transforms, image, video

first of all sry for my bad english. :/

I want to know if there ist any tutorial for Blender to made an Transition VideoSequence or something for a Twitch/Stream Szene change, dont know if Transition is the right word for it..

i have 3 parts of a pic (made by hand in gimp) and Blender have to put them together, for example the upper part from the top down, and the two lower parts from the bottom corners up, so that the picture is complete after the slide in.

i hope u guys understand what i want. :/

[image: raw draw]

EDIT:

this is my current state:

[image]

so i dont know how to set the keyframes to the coordinates!?
i think i have to set the coords to zero @ frame 30 f.ex.
and then set the coords like in the picture? But how does that work?

And after that i think i have to click on 'Render -> Render Animation' right?

Comment: You will probably have a hard tome doing this in the Vide Sequence editor alone. Do it with textured planes in the 3D view.

Comment: There is no automated transition effect for that. I think the easiest way is to the use import image as plane addon, then cut the plane into pieces and animate the pieces coming together and add that to the VSE.

Comment: You can do this with 3x VSE Transform effect strips and masks.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do using the compositor.

- In the UV/Image editor create a series of masks, one for each piece of the image.

  [image]
- In the compositor use each mask as alpha channel on the image, connect each element to a transform node and combine them using alpha over nodes.

  [image]
- we are going to construct the movement backwards, starting from the end of the animation.

  Move in the timeline to the frame that will be the end of the animation (where all of the elements are combined) and set a key frame for the transformation cooridinates.

  [image]
- In the time line go to the frame of the animation where you want the motion to start and move the values for the transformation so that each of the elements has moved away and set a keyframe.

  - The elements should move now to the end position.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. But I'll get stuck before the last steps i think. I dont know how to set the frames to the coordinates. Oh man how can i upload a picture in an comment?